# Detect scroll - Ionic 4

Tags: angular, scroll, ionic4, direction

I'm trying to detect when I scroll up with:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" scrollY="true">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Before with Ionic 3 I detected it in the following way:

```
  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {

    this.infiniteScroll = infiniteScroll;
    if(infiniteScroll._content.directionY == "up"){
       //paginate
    }
  }
```

But now with Ionic 4 I do not know how to detect 'directionY'

A greeting

Answer (score 3):

You can use scroll events on the ion content.

```
<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)"></ion-content>
```

Then in your ts file

```
onScroll(event) {
        if (event.detail.deltaY > 0) {
            console.log('scrolling down...');
        } else if (event.detail.deltaY < 0) {
            console.log('scrolling up...');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the content view child.

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
```

---

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    this.infiniteScroll = infiniteScroll;
    this.content.scrollToTop(1000) //add 1 second animation to make it smoother
  }
```